# Поддомены и роутинг в laravel

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, nginx

Как на laravel можно организовать динамический роутинг по поддоменам для реферальной системы?
Те нужно к примеру с поддомена user1.example.com фиксировать реф при регистрации пользователя.
Сам сервер на ubuntu + nginx и я не представляю как можно динамически создавать нужные мне поддомены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) В ДНС своего домена внесите А-запись вида ***.site.com** (таким образом все домены третьего уровня будут направляться на ваш сервер)

2) В роутере Laravel пропишите правило

```
   Route::domain('{account}.site.com')->group(function () {
            Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
                //здесь ваша функция
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

ну надо написать конфиг на подобие такого

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name "~^(?<sub>.+)\.domain\.tld$";

  root /path/to/document/root/;
  // .... конфиг для php ... 
  // если нужно будет можно заюзать $sub - поддомен
}
```

Далее можно как и при try files передавать этот поддомен в request либо в переменную окружение, даже подсказку дам, к примеру в эту `APP_URL=$shema.$subdomain.youdomain.tld` ну и оперировать ими в laravel